# Low-level read file

Tags: c, linux, file

```
#include <fcntl.h> 
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <string.h> 
#include <sys/stat.h> 
#include <sys/types.h> 
#include <unistd.h> 

int main (int argc, char* argv[]) 

{

  char* filename = argv[1]; 

  /* Open the file for writing. If it exists, append to it; 

     otherwise, create a new file.  */ 

  int fd = open (filename, O_RDONLY | O_CREAT | O_APPEND, 0666); 

// Reading file probleme

  close (fd); 

  return 0; 

}
```

My problem is that I can't really find how to read to buffer. I have only ints in the file but how can I read from it to that buffer? I can't find functions to achieve that.

Comment: It seems to me that your problem would be fixed by reading tutorials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function you're looking for is called "read". You have to pass it a buffer you've already allocated previously, however. Something like this ought to work:

```
if (fd) {
  char buffer[1024];
  int n = read(fd, buffer, 1024);

  /* ... */
}
```

after that call, n will contain the number of bytes read from the fd (or 0 for none or less than 0 if an error occured).

If you have raw ints in that file, you could then access them kinda like this:

```
int *ibuffer = (int*)buffer;
```

ibuffer is then an array of ints of length 1024/sizeof(int) containing the first n/sizeof(int) consecutive ints in fd. Strictly speaking this isn't quite legal C, but then I haven't seen an architecture lately where this wouldn't have worked.

Comment: if i have more then 1024 i need to make a new read and i will alocate the buffer in another one? the ints are represented in binary form .

Comment: It'd be best if you did that read() in a loop and allocated `buffer` on the fly with malloc(), then increased its size with realloc(). If you've never done that before, however, the process can be rather intimidating. Depending on the architecture you're going to run this programme on, however, you should be fine to increase the size of the buffer up to about 8 mibibytes - that's (8*1024*1024). (I've done some testing back in the days, that's when stuff started going wrong.)

Answer (score 0):

Do you have ints represented as strings or as bytes? If strings just use `sscanf` on your buffer to read it. For byte representation you can just read the raw bytes from buffer.

Comment: i can use only low level functions its a sample question on a bigger problem. its on ints .

Comment: @user1922551 What do you mean "low level" functions? use read() to read contents into a buffer and sscanf to read ints from that buffer.

Comment: @user1922551: Low-level is a very subjective things. read() system call is very high-level some but low level for others.